# asp.net MVC, Bootstrap and CSS. Drop down list issue

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why Chrome is not rendering my drop down list correctly.

[image: Chrome Error]

However, it renders correctly in IE

[image: IE Error]

This is the line of code that is displaying this list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", size = "18px" })
```

I am using the default Boostrap.css files provided by starting a new project in Visual Studio 2013.  Any idea how to get this to render correctly?

Comment: show the rendered html output also. it looks like one is being rendered as "multiple" and one is not. odd.

Comment: Remove the `size = "18px"` (it invalid and the correct usage is `size="18"` is you want to display 18 items, but since you do not want to display any items, just delete it)

Comment: Stephen Muecke,  This was the answer I was looking for.  I guess I overlooked this fact.  Could you please make this an answer so I can accept it as so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creating invalid html, and there is no guarantee how various browsers (or even versions of the same browser) will handle invalid html.

Your `DropDownListFor()` method is adding a `size` attribute which expects an integer value so `size="18px"` is invalid and it would need to be `size="18"`. However the `size` attribute defines how many items to display in a multiple select, so since you do not want a multiple select, just remove the attribute. Your code should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Side note: Your `new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text")` code suggest that `CountryList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If that is the case, its pointless extra overhead to be creating a new `SelectList` from an existing `SelectList` so your code should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.CountryList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `htmlAttributes` to set your class in your razor. So change your code to :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes:new { @class = "form-control", size = "18px" })
```